# Integration of ui-grid-treeview and ui-grid-grouping

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Can we apply ui-grid-treeview in total resultset and ui-grid-grouping 
in any of the column together.

For example I want to create a hierarchical view of all the employees (using ui-grid-treeview) and again grouping subordinates of a particular employee using their location (using ui-grid-grouping).

Comment: Can anybody help me to resolve this problem